# Teamcity - Push changes without building (in commit message)

Tags: git, teamcity

Is there a way to push up a commit containing a param in the commit message such as "--nobuild" which would disable building the project in TeamCity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you should change your build trigger. There are trigger rules, and you can add new rule `-:comment=--nobuild:**` More info: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers

Comment: Verified, this is the correct way of doing this.  Be good if you could have triggers for individual steps too.

Comment: Does this still allow a subsequent push to be build ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Branch Filters unfortunately.